# Get input before submitting to insert into action url

Tags: javascript, php

Im trying to get a value of an input into my buttons action url before the button is pushed.

I need to get the value of:

```
id="qty<?php echo $i;?>"
```

Into where it says:

```
<?php echo VALUE OF $qtyforaction; ?>
```

My Code is:

```
       <?php $i = $_product->getId();?>

            <form action="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>

                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty<?php echo $i;?>" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="cartnum" />

                <?php $qtyforaction = 'qty'.$i; ?>
                <?php echo $qtyforaction; ?>


                <button type="button" class="addtocartbutton button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>qty/<?php echo VALUE OF $qtyforaction; ?>')" ><span><span>Order Again</span></span></button>

          </form>
```

Would I have to use javascript to get it into the url string? My javascript is a bit ropey, would something like this work?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var something= document.getElementById('<?php echo $qtyforaction;?>');
     </script>
```

UPDATE WITH FULL CODE:

```
<?php
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

/* Get the customer data */
$customer       = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
/* Get the customer's email address */
$customer_email = $customer->getEmail();

}

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', array(
'like' => $customer_email
));



$uniuqProductSkus = array();

foreach ($collection as $order) { 

    $order_id = $order->getId(); 
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); 
    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems(); 
        foreach ($ordered_items as $item) 
        { 
        if (in_array($item->getProduct()->getSku(), $uniuqProductSkus)) { 
        continue; 
        } else { 
            array_push($uniuqProductSkus, $item->getProduct()->getSku()); 

            $_product                 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $product_small_image_path = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200);
            $product_thumbnail_path   = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150);
            $summaryData              = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->load($item->getProductId());

            echo "<li>";

            echo "<div class='previous-name'><p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
            echo $item->getName() . "</a></p></div>";

            echo "<div class='previous-image'><a href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
            echo "<img src='" . $product_small_image_path . "' />";
            echo "</a></div>";

            echo "<div class='previous-rating'>";
            echo "<p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "#product_tabs_review_tabbed'>Review this beer now</a></p>";

            echo $summaryData->getRatingSummary() . '% Would buy again <br/>';

            echo "<div class='rating-box' style='float:left;'>";
            echo "<div class='rating' style='width:" . $summaryData->getRatingSummary() . "%'></div></div>";
            echo "</div>";


            /**echo "<div class='previous-button'>";
            echo '<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation(\'';
            echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
            echo '\')"><span><span>Order Again</span></span></button>';
            echo "</div>";**/

            ?>

            <?php $i = $_product->getId();?>
            <div class='previous-button'>
            <form action="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>

                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty<?php echo $i;?>" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="cartnum" />

                <?php $qtyforaction = 'qty'.$i; ?>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var xy = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("qty");
                    var x = "<button type='button' class='addtocartbutton  button btn-cart' onclick='setLocation()'><span><span>Order Again</span></span></button>";
                     document.getElementById("buttonaddcart").innerHTML = x;
                 </script>
                 <div id="buttonaddcart">
                <button type="button" class="addtocartbutton button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>qty/')" ><span><span>Order Again</span></span></button>
                 </div>

            </form>
            </div>


            <?php
            echo "<div class='previous-clear'></div>";

            echo "</li>";

    }
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the id attribute:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("id");
```

But how do you plan on using PHP to echo out this variable if PHP is loaded and done with before Javascript even comes into play? You could use Javascript though to display this variable on the page if that's all you needed.

If you had something in your HTML to target, you could do it like this:

```
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
```

But anyways, get the action attribute value...

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getAttribute("action");
```

Then set the action attribute to this + the qty...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].setAttribute("action", x + y);
```

That should work for you, if not, try wrapping `x + y` in additional parentheses...`("action", (x + y));`

Comment: Thank you, I now just need to display that variable, how would I do that?

Comment: thanks, how does javascript handle in a php loop? It seems to work for the first thing in the loop but not the ones after?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't see any PHP loops in your code?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is now or what you're trying to do.

Comment: The line <?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?> produces a URL I want to get the qty from the qty input and add it to the url when the submit button is pushed